# Why I can't get the associated object from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get associated object from another class

My code is :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
static char NUMBER ='a';

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSNumber *num=@10;
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &NUMBER, num, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
    return self;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person *p=[[Person alloc]init];
    NSNumber *num=objc_getAssociatedObject(p, &NUMBER);
    NSLog(@"%@",num);
}

@end
```

`NSLog(@"%@",num)` is null.

Why can't I get the associated object from the above code. Can't we get the associated object from another class ? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your key. You probably define this classes in different files. Do not use `static` keyword, static variables can only be accessed within a single translation unit. This means you have new copy of `NUMBER` for each file. Remove `static` keyword and add `extern` declaration in Person.h header:

Person.h:

```
extern const char NUMBER;

@interface Person : NSObject
@end
```

Person.m:

```
#import "Person.h"
#import "objc/runtime.h"

const char NUMBER ='a';

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSNumber *num = @10;
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &NUMBER, num, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    Person *p = [[Person alloc]init];
    NSNumber *num = objc_getAssociatedObject(p, &NUMBER);
    NSLog(@"%@",num);
}

@end
```